# Format problem in a construction of a loop in python

Tags: python, list

Following is the piece of program:

```
import numpy as np
def f(num):
  return np.piecewise(num, [(num+1)%3==1, (num+2)%3==0,(num+1)%3==0], [1,-1,-1])
print(f(0))
print(f(1))
fx = [[f(i),i,(i+1)%2] for i in range(2)] 
print(fx)
```

Output:

```
  1
 -1
  [[array(1), 0, 1], [array(-1), 1, 0]]
```

I am expecting following output for the construction: `fx = [[f(i),i,(i+1)%2] for i in range(2)]`

```
 [[1.0, 0, 1], [-1.0, 1, 0]]
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `item` function:

```py
fx = [[f(i).item(), i, (i + 1) % 2] for i in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're returning a numpy array, which is returned as array([data]). If you use the `item()` function you can fetch it's value.

```
fx = [[f(i).item(), i, (i + 1) % 2] for i in range(2)]
```

If you have multiple values in the array, then use you can use `item(n)`.